# How can I intercept the result of an IQueryProvider query (other than single result)

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework and I have a custum IQueryProvider. I use the Execute method so that I can modify the result (a POCO) of a query after is has been executed. I want to do the same for collections. The problem is that the Execute method is only called for single result.

As described on MSDN :

> The Execute method executes queries that return a single value
>   (instead of an enumerable sequence of values). Expression trees that
>   represent queries that return enumerable results are executed when
>   their associated IQueryable object is enumerated.

Is there another way to accomplish what I want that I missed?

I know I could write a specific method inside a repository or whatever but I want to apply this to all possible queries.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The final answer is that it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is true that the actual signature is:

```
public object Execute(Expression expression)
public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
```

However, *that does not mean* that the TResult will always be a single element! It is the type expected to be returned from the expression.

Also, note that there are *no constraints* over the `TResult`, not even 'class' or 'new()'.

The TResult is a `MyObject` when your expression is of singular result, like `.FirstOrDefault()`. However, the TResult can also be a `double` when you `.Avg()` over the query, and also it can be `IEnumerable<MyObject>` when your query is plain `.Select.Where`.

Proof(*) - I've just set a breakpoint inside my Execute() implementation, and I've inspected it with Watches:

```
typeof(TResult).FullName    "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[xxxxxx,xxxxx]]"
expression.Type.FullName    "System.Linq.IQueryable`1[[xxxxxx,xxxxx]]"
```

I admit that three overloads, one `object`, one `TResult` and one `IEnumerable<TResult>` would probably be more readable. I think they did not place three of them as extensibility point for future interfaces. I can imagine that in future they came up with something more robust than `IEnumerable`, and then they'd need to add another overload and so on. With simple  this interface can process **any type**.

Oh, see, we now also have `IQueryable` in addition to `IEnumerable`, so it would need at least four overloads:)

The Proof is marked with (*) because I have had a small bug/feature in my IQueryProvider's code that has is obscuring the real behavior of LINQ.

LINQ indeed calls the generic Execute only for singular cases. This is a shortcut, an **optimization**.

For all other cases, it ... **doesn't call Execute() it at all**

For those all other cases, the LINQ calls `.GetEnumerator` on your custom `IQueryable<>` implementation, that what happens is dictated by .. simply what you wrote there. I mean, assuming that you actually provided custom implementations of IQueryable. That would be strange if you did not - that's just about 15 lines in total, nothing compared to the length of custom provider.

In the project where I got the "proof" from, my implementation looks like:

```
public System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    return Provider.Execute<IEnumerable>( this.Expression ).GetEnumerator();
}

public IEnumerator<TOut> GetEnumerator()
{
    return Provider.Execute<IEnumerable<TOut>>( this.Expression ).GetEnumerator();
}
```

of course, one of them would be explicit due to name collision. Please note that to fetch the enumerator, I actually call the Execute with explicitely stated TResult. This is why in my "proof" those types occurred.

I think that you see the "TResult = Single Element" case, because you wrote i.e. something like this:

```
public IEnumerator<TOut> GetEnumerator()
{
    return Provider.Execute<TOut>( this.Expression ).GetEnumerator();
}
```

Which really renders your Execute implementation without choice, and must return single element. IMHO, this is just a bug in your code. You could have done it like in my example above, or you could simply use the untyped Execute:

```
public System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    return ((IEnumerable)Provider.Execute( this.Expression )).GetEnumerator();
}

public IEnumerator<TOut> GetEnumerator()
{
    return ((IEnumerable<TOut>)Provider.Execute( this.Expression )).GetEnumerator();
}
```

Of course, your implementation of Execute must make sure to return proper IEnumerables for such queries!

Answer (score 0):

> Expression trees that represent queries that return enumerable results are executed when their associated IQueryable object is enumerated.

I recommend enumerating your query:

```
foreach(T t in query)
{
  CustomModification(t);
}
```

---

Your IQueryProvider must implement [`CreateQuery<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549043.aspx).  You get to choose the implemenation of the resulting IQueryable.  If you want that IQueryable to do something to each row when enumerated, you get to write that implementation.

Comment: Yes, this would work if it was ONE query. But I am building a framework and I don't have a single point where I can enumerate the query. I want to sit right on top of Entity Framework for EVERY queries. As I said, I would want the exact equivalent of the Execute method of IQueryProvider but for enumerated results.